# mod_rewrite for folder and its containing pages

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

.htaccess Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^articles/([-a-z]+)\.html$ articles/article.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

I have a folder [articles] which contains two pages:

index.php and 
article.php

The first page shows the list of articles and the second one actually fetches the actual article from the database using a parameter [slug] and displays it.

```
site.com/articles/this-is-an-article-title.html
site.com/articles/article.php?slug=this-is-an-article-title
```

The code is working fine but the problem is I cannot see the list of articles on index.php and it is going through the RewriteRule mistakenly.

How do I stop this?

Comment: So you're saying `/articles/index.php` is piped through articles.php, even though it's not covered by the RewriteRule? - (Btw, it's often advisable to *not* have files and folders identical to the *virtual* incoming request paths. It's strictly unneeded that they match up).

Comment: I want to get /articles/ and /articles/this-is-an-article-title.html (Currently I can have the second one. /articles/ not loading /articles/index.php file

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule is possibly picking up the implicit `/articles/index.html` when requesting the `articles/` dir.

1. Disable that per:

   ```
    DirectoryIndex index.php
   ```
2. Or write a custom RewriteRule to prevent any automatic mapping:

   ```
    RewriteRule ^articles/*$ articles/index.php [L]
   ```
3. Optionally also disable `Options -MultiViews`

   (This is likely not an issue in your case. But hard to tell without a RewriteLog / access.log excerpt.)

Comment: Can I have this patterns as well?

site.com/articles/
site.com/articles/2/
site.com/articles/3/
site.com/articles/4/ 
site.com/articles/5/